# Eclipse Javascript Error Highlighting

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide

I'm using `Eclipse 3.4.2 Ganymede`...

with the `Web and Java EE Environment` add-on installed.

I have a `Dynamic Web Project` with a number of scripts and html pages in it.

In my HTML file, I've added a few scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/getpoints.js"></script>
```

Since the `getpoints.js` file does not directly reference `dojo.js`, Eclipse's error/warning highlightings in `getpoints.js` are useless.

---

How can I get Eclipse to detect this relationship correctly and display the correct errors/warnings?

---

Edit: for reference, these are the predominant errors

```
dojo cannot be resolved
XMLHttpRequest cannot be resolved or is not a field
ActiveXObject cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

as well as a few more related to specifics of the project.

---

Solutions:

- I found out that if I add a number of my js files to my sources and browser globals, I solved some of my errors.

Project -> Properties -> Javascript -> Javascript Libraries -> Source -> Add File from Project`
Project -> Properties -> Javascript -> Javascript Libraries -> Global Supertypes -> Select & Reorder Libraries

- My ajax related errors came from accidentally declaring `var http`.
- Dojo's error was minimized by the solution given below.

Comment: This answer may be relevant and useful: http://superuser.com/a/482260/85129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If getpoints.js is your own script, you could put a line at the top like:

```
var dojo = dojo || {};
```

That should silence the warnings.

I think Eclipse is behaving correctly, though, because it can't know that getpoints.js will always have dojo included in the HTML file. It's just checking the syntax/semantics of getpoints.js and, technically, the script won't stand on its own. Adding the above line will 'fix' the problem by making sure that dojo is always defined.

Comment: So there's really no way for eclipse to highlight errors with respect to the entire project rather than the file?

Comment: No, but you could retry it with something more current.  Ganymede is old.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse `var dojo = dojo || {};` throws:

> The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) any,
>   ___anonymous708_709